# To Add bg color inside the space of an single letter in a word

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to add color for an single letter which have space in a word.

For example if we have a word name 'Does' I need to fill the color for the letter 'o' and 'e' in which i need the color inside the space of the letter I want the bg color inside the space of a letter thats my requirement.

I have attached a image in that check the letter 'o,B,P'which have bg color inside the space.[image: check this image]

Comment: Not possible with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D why its not possible can you tell me ?

Comment: The easiest way of doing this would be to create an image that looks like the text that you want with the spaces colored and use the image instead of the text. The only other way I could think of doing it is to position boxes of that color behind the text and do a lot of careful positioning but that will have a lot of issues.

Comment: **It just isn't.** You can't have multicolor fonts and there is no way to color individual sections of a character. Also the background of the character applied to all of the character, not just part.

Comment: @Sri: There is no "select any letter with a space in" css selector. You may find someone has developed a script for this, or a custom font - but I'm 99.99% sure this isn't possible.

Comment: @Professor.CSS how can we achive this with script?

Comment: Taka using image will create several problem I want to achive this in css only any other idea please let me know

Comment: This requires creating custom images.  Built-in font support in HTML and most other apps have no concept of having a separate color for inner spaces (a.k.a. the "counter").  
You might be able to get around to some extent this with some sort of server-side dynamic text-to-image library (maybe PHP GD?), depending on what platform you have available to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **is** perfectly possible, even using css only, but you will have to create a customized solution for every letter and font, and you must wrap the letters which need this CSS in spans and give them the appropriate classes.

Check the pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVRLap

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.fill-letter {
  position: relative;
}
.fill-letter:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
.o:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>H<span class="fill-letter o">O</span>ME</h1>
```

Comment: This would work, yes, but for the amount of time creating the font-styling, you'd be at this near enough for the next decade...with thousands of fonts available and many letters having 'holes' in.

Comment: Well noone asked for a solutions that works on every font. I assume the OP needs a solution for just *one* font - this effort will be like 1 or 2 hours probably.